Is it possible for $\mathsf{PA} \vdash \varphi(b)$, for every $b \in \mathbb{N}$, but with no repeated proofs?
Suppose I have an $\mathcal{L}(\mathsf{PA})$-formula $\varphi(b)$ with free variable $b$, and suppose that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\mathsf{PA}\vdash \varphi(n)$. Is it possible that there is no fixed sequent calculus proof which shows $\varphi(n)$ for infinitely many $n$? By a fixed sequent calculus proof, I mean a proof that is uniformly generatable by, say, a Turing machine which is given input $n$ and then outputs the sequent calculus proof where $\mathsf{PA}\vdash \varphi(n)$.
If this were false, then that would mean there is some $\varphi(b)$ of which $\mathsf{PA} \vdash \varphi(b)$, for every $b\in\mathbb{N}$, but there is no shared proof that works for infinitely many $b$. That seems impossible to me, but I am really not sure.

Let $\varphi(n)$ be "there is no proof that Peano arithmetic is inconsistent with length $n$". Assuming PA is consistent, then PA shows $\varphi(n)$ (in fact, very weak theories can show that) by enumerating all those finitely many proofs and checking them. But PA cannot show $\forall n. \varphi(n)$.

Why does that seem impossible to you? I always think of induction as a way to write an outline of an infinite proof. But there are uncountably many possible infinite proofs, and only countably many that can be so "outlined" using induction. It seems likely that there are infinite proofs like yours which cannot be written as a finite proof.

@Trebor I am not asking for a Kreisel Conjecture-type statement like asking PA to prove the universalized statement. I'm asking if a single proof template must be shared by infinitely many $n$. Your example actually falls in line with what I am saying. The 'brute force' sequent calculus proof is the same for every numeral $n$

@ThomasAndrews What do you mean infinite proof? By Godel's completeness theorem,
there are no infinite proofs.

I mean that intuitively, a proof by induction is an outline for an infinite proof. I prove for $n=0,$ then $n=1,$ then $n=2,\dots.$ There exists a lot more intuitive infinite proofs than can be written using induction. I was talking about your intuition about it being impossible, and giving a mental framework about why such a thing is not intuitive at all. It is not a formal argument, it is an intuitive argument. @StefanG.

I would add, the concept of infinitely often and all can easily be switched between. If $\rho(p)$ is a statement, infinitely often is equivalent to $\forall p\exists n\ geq p(\rho(n))$ and visa versa, all $p$ can be written as "there are infinitely many $p$ such that for all $n<p$ $\rho(n).$ So singling out "infinitely often" is irrelevant. You can restrict to $\forall p(\phi(p)).$

A simple example is the Goldbach conjecture. You can write it as $\phi(p)$ being "For all $n\leq p$ with $n>1,$ we can write $2n$ as the sum of two primes." Your argument is that, intuitively, if Goldbach is true, it has a proof, because we can easily write a proof of $\phi(p)$ for each $p$ by enumerating all the finite cases for $n\leq p.$ There is no intuitive reason to expect a pattern in those proofs.

Another example would be the twin prime conjecture, where $\phi(p)$ would be "$p$ and $p+2$ are prime." If the twin prime conjecture is true, we know we can get a program to write a proof of $\phi(p)$ for infinitely many $p,$ but it doesn't give us any intuition that there exists a finite proof for infinitely many $p.$

@ThomasAndrews The proofs in these examples are the same according to the definition I gave in my post. Take the twin primes example. I have a Turing machine that on input $p$, outputs the sequent calculus proof from PA axioms that $p$ and $p+2$ are prime.

It depends highly on what you mean by "template." E.g. consider the following: "on input $n$, search for a $\mathsf{PA}$-proof of $\varphi(n)$ and halt and output one once found." If $\mathsf{PA}$ does in fact prove each $\varphi(n)$, then this is a computable process which generates a $\mathsf{PA}$-proof of $\varphi(n)$ for each $n$, uniformly in $n$. Does this fit? If not, why not?

I agree with Noah. If we know a PA proof exists, then it can always be computably found by brute force. So if as you replied to me, brute forcing counts as a so called "proof template", then the question trivializes.
